# NSTimezone not giving GMT+ or GMT- formate iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nstimezone

I am getting total number of seconds for the timezone but not getting it is ahead of GMT Or behind to GMT. Here is my code.

```
NSDate *sourceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600 * 24 * 60];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
int totalSeconds = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSLog(@"sourceDate=%@ timeZoneOffset=%d", sourceDate, totalSeconds);
```

I want to know it is GMT + or GMT -
For example
India time zone is GMT+5:30 i am getting total 19800 seconds with this code but how to know it is GMT+ .

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seconds returned is an integer value, which will be positive or negative depending on the offset from the GMT.

Also, you might want to read through the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It discusses this in the very first section.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read the documentation but not getting how to done it. Please guide me toward any method or property available for that or provide me any code if you have

Comment: You say the seconds returned is 19800. That means it is GMT+. If you had a value of -19800, then it would be GMT-.

Comment: Thank you . Yes you are right body. I am getting -10800 for Regina - Canada. My code is correct.

Comment: Sorry its -21600 for Regina - Canada.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting are correct, if it's GMT- you will get a negative value, you can use the following check:

```
if (totalSeconds >= 0){
    // it's GMT+
} else {
    // it's GMT-
}
```